# When uploading a file via metafield "File reference", how can I display it to the front theme?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

As seen in the documentation below, it is possible to upload a PDF file using File referance metafield. However, I cannot get it to work when displaying it to the front end in a theme. Are there any working examples for this? Thank you.

[image: Documentation]

Comment: As per documentation, it returns the downloaded link for other files, so if you try to display the PDF file on frontend for display purpose, you need to try the iframe tag to display the content of PDF file.

Answer (score 1):

In Liquid you can use `file_url` filter to get the URL and use iframe to display the PDF document preview:

```
<iframe src="{{ product.metafields.my_fields.name_of_pdf_field | file_url }}"></iframe>
```